# While script inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

pretty straight forward question this - I am trying to create an array to store the Model and Cost values taken from my database table. I figured I could begin the array, then create a while loop, and then end the array, and smiles all around. I may be mistaken, or I may have blindly missed something in my code, but could you have a look?

```
$array = array(
    while ($overall_cost = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ocost)) {
            $overall_cost["model"] => $overall_cost["cost"],
    }
);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? It's syntactically wrong...

Comment: Not just syntactically. This is wrong in many other ways.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Of course it's wrong, otherwise I would have not posted for help. This site isn't about boasting skill, I am clearly unaware of how to do this and wanted your input.

Thanks NullPointer for your resources. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$array = array();

while ($overall_cost = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ocost)) {
    $array[$overall_cost["model"]] = $overall_cost["cost"];
}

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Great, that makes sense now I see it. This will come in handy in the future too, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it like this. You need to add to the array inside the while loop:

```
$array = array();
while ($overall_cost = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ocost)) {
        $array[$overall_cost["model"]] = $overall_cost["cost"];
}    

var_dump($array);
```

would be one way of doing it.

EDITED to produce simple array.

Comment: Which is how the OP had it (albeit wrongly) in his post. I don't think it was worth a downvote.

Comment: Actually the OP didn't have it as a multi-dimensional array.  If PHP worked like he thought, it would have created this:

$array = array(something => something,
  something => something,
);

I didn't vote you down though.

Comment: I didn't spend hours figuring this one out, I simply tried what I thought would work with little experience in creating arrays. My example gave you a clear understanding of what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your response GarethL.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will work. Try something like:

```
$array = array();
while ($overall_cost = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_ocost)) {
      $array[$overall_cost["model"]] = $overall_cost["cost"];
}


var_dump($array);
```